# Recursive time series segmentation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-series, linear-regression

Im doing Time series analysis on stock market data and trying to implement an algorithm for piecewise linear segmentation, which is as follows :

```
    split(T [ta, tb ]) – split a time series T of length
    n from time ta to time tb where 0 ≤ a < b ≤ n
    1: Ttemp = ∅
    2: εmin = ∞;
    3: εtotal = 0;
    4: for i = a to b do
            5:εi = (pi − pi )^2 ;
            6:if εmin > εi then
                7:  εmin = εi ;
                8:  tk = ti ;
            9:end if
        10:εtotal = εtotal + εi ;
    11: end for
    12: ε = εtotal /(tb − ta );
    13: if t-test.reject(ε) then
            14:Ttemp = Ttemp ∪ split(T [ta , tk ]);
            15:Ttemp = Ttemp ∪ split(T [tk , tb ]);
        16: end if
    17: return Ttemp ;
```

My time series class is as follows :

```
class MySeries{
      ArrayList<Date> time;
      Double[] value;
}
```

In the above algorithm, Ttemp is another instance of a timeseries. The calculations from lines 4-12 are for calculating error.
The problem is that Im not able to implement the recursion and the union parts above (lines 14 and 15).Im not clear how to recurse and make a union of MySeries objects.

*******************EDIT***********************************

```
class Segmentation{
    static MySeries series1 = new MySeries();    //contains the complete time series
    static HashSet<MySeries> series_set = new HashSet<MySeries>();    

    public static MySeries split(MySeries series, int start, int limit) throws ParseException{      
        if(limit-start < 3){     //get min of 3 readings atleast
        return null;
        }

    tTemp = MySeries.createSegment(series1, start, limit);

    double emin = 999999999, e,etotal=0, p, pcap;
    DescriptiveStatistics errors = new DescriptiveStatistics();

    for(int i=start;i<limit;i++){
        p = series1.y[i];
        pcap = series1.regress.predict(series1.x[i]);
        e = (p-pcap)*(p-pcap);
        errors.addValue(e);
        if(emin > e){
            emin = e;
            splitPoint = i;
        }
        etotal = etotal + e;
    }
    e = etotal/(limit-start);

    double std_dev_error = errors.getStandardDeviation();
    double tTstatistic = e/(std_dev_error/Math.sqrt(errors.getN()));

        if(ttest.tTest(tTstatistic, errors, 0.10)){
            union(split(series1, start, splitPoint));
            union(split(series1, splitPoint+1, limit));
        }
    return tTemp;
}

    static void union(MySeries ms){
        series_set.add(ms);    
    }
}
```

I've written the above code for the given algorithm..but i dnt know why it runs into infinite loop..
I'll be thankful if someone can please provide me with any other design or modification of the code.

Comment: `(pi - pi)^2` -- isn't that just `0`?

Comment: No its actually (pi -pi_cap)^2..mathematcial terms..dont bother with that.

Comment: We're the code for the `split` function? When you get that it looks to me like you just need to do a union (u) of the sets (equivalent to `hashSet.addAll`.

Comment: sorry for the mistake..the algorithm's name itself is split..so on lines 14 and 15 it is calling itself recursively.

Comment: What @Perception meant is that when you implement your method you can use `HashSet` as type for Ttemp and use a line like `Ttemp.addAll(split(timeseries));` to perform the join of the data returned by the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

> i dnt know why it runs into infinite loop

It's easy to find out why. Just insert some print statements to see what's going on (or use a debugger). For instance,

```
    if(ttest.tTest(tTstatistic, errors, 0.10)){
        System.out.printf("About to split %d .. %d .. %d%n", start, splitPoint, limit);
        union(split(series1, start, splitPoint));
        union(split(series1, splitPoint+1, limit));
    }
    else
        System.out.printf("Not splitting %d .. %d%n", start, limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your εi is always zero! Thus your if statement following εi = (pi - pi )^2 will always be true!